# Maxing out HDD reading speed in Java for fast parsing

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, parsing, buffer

I've got huge text files (3-digit-GB) representing several objects in the following format (// and <> are just my comments):

```
1) [attr1 "value1"] // Object 1
2) [attr2 "value2"]
3) [attr3 "value3"]
4) [attr4 "value4"]
5)
6) <stuff about object 1 I'm not interested in>
7)
8) [attr1 "value1"] // Object 2
9) [attr2 "value2"]
10) [attr3 "value3"]
11) [attr4 "value4"]
12)
13) <stuff about object 2 I'm not interested in>
14)
...and so on
```

I'd like to create rows in my database of the form value2, value3
So I programmed it using BufferedReader's readline putting [value2, value3] as a little class of mine into a LinkedList to be read by another thread inserting them into the database as soon as there are 1_000_000. I thought that this would get the most out of my HDD's reading speed.
But instead of 190 MB/s I get only about 135 MB/s, the reason being my CPU not being able to parse at that speed. The core of the parser thread kind of spikes up and down in the 90%-100% region.

Through testing I've discovered, that reading big byte[] arrays and converting them to strings in one go uses the HDD a lot more since it's faster on the CPU. So my idea was to put the byte arrays into a queue to be worked off by several threads. However the byte[] could end in the middle of a line and therefore ruin the parsing or require (complicated?) communication between the threads in order to fix this. Also lines of one object will be split up between two threads which is not nice.

side note: I think I've kind of found the fastest parsing algorithm for this particular format:
Just scan until you've found '[attr2 "' (without the '') take value2, then the same for attr3 then store the object to the queue. The order of the attributes is the same, but there might be some attributes inbetween in some rare cases.
Question is how to make multiple threads do this working on a different byte-array each.

Yeah, so that's my current problem, I want this stuff to be parsed as fast as possible and am therefore asking for your wisdom :)

My best thought so far is having each thread lay aside the first and last (probably broken) lines into some datastructure in order for them to be fixed later on (I don't care about the order of the objects).

You probably have a simpler, faster, better idea?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that you will be able to "max out" your HDD's read speed.  Not in Java.  Not in any language.

Comment: The HDD's only purpose is to have those files stored and be read. It has no other job, nothing is using it. When I use large byte[] arrays it gets very very close to it's max reading speed

Answer (score 1):

If your performance is CPU bound, as you believe it is, then you are right that getting multiple cores parsing in parallel is the way to go.

I would try having a single thread which creates buffers containing a number of complete rows, and then sends those buffers to a pool of parsing threads. This single thread would be a bottleneck, but I think you might be able to make it fast enough.

I would read a buffer, *not* do any string conversion, just leave it as byte[], and then scan backwards from the end to find any partial rows. Send this buffer to be parsed, along with a size which tells the parser not to parse the partial row. Hopefully the scanning backwards is as simple as 'scan until you find a "]'', unless escaped ']' characters can appear in the values.

Copy the partial row to the start of the next buffer, then read more bytes directly after the partial row, and so on.

Then each parsing thread has complete rows to work with.

The bottleneck thread is fast, because it only scans the last few bytes of each buffer before passing it on.

There are other things you could do, such as statically allocating the buffers to avoid gc and doing all the parsing in a byte[] instead of String, but I think that's premature optimisation.

Comment: That would still split the objects between buffers because one object consists of multiple lines. Therefore I have to scan backwards until I find '[last_attribute_I_want "<value>"]', right?

Comment: Yes, it would split the objects. So along with the length of the buffer you would need to pass a block sequence number which would allow matching value2 from block n with value3 from block n+1, to avoid scanning far. But this is getting complicated, I think @rici has a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's no good reason why having data split over two consecutive buffers should cause major complications.

Assuming the data of interest is short relative to the buffer size (which seems likely, since you say the buffers are chosen to be very big), buffer splits in the middle of interesting data will be very rare, so an ultra-efficient solution is not necessary. The simple solution, therefore, is for the reading thread to just fall back to reading the next block of data in order to complete the interesting data. Of course, that data has already been read, but reading it twice is not going to cause any harm.

(The thread has to read the next data block even if it hasn't yet completed the match of `[attr2` when it reaches the end of the buffer. But if it turns out that what it has wasn't `[attr2`, it just terminates.)

This strategy will not result in the same `[attr2` being processed by more than one thread, because it is only processed by the thread which was given the buffer which contains the first character of the pattern. And, as mentioned above, it will not significantly increase the number of disk reads performed. (Depending on your OS and machine load, it might not increase the number of disk reads at all, because it's possible that the data block is still in the OS's buffer cache.)

Comment: Wow, thanks, so simple. Of course the byte[] array one thread has taken can also be read by another thread!

Answer (score 1):

Without the actual code, it's close to impossible to find the CPU bottleneck.

So, get yourself a decent profiler (at our company we use JProfiler) to find out the method/code line consuming most of the CPU.

While profiling, your application will run like 10x slower than normal, but the relative times spent in the various parts will stay rather representative for the normal execution.

Often, you'll find a single method call consuming 90% of the CPU. Optimize that one.